# how to retrieve data from the data dictionary in oracle?

Tags: plsql

I'm new in this so I have maybe dumb question.
I need to retrieve INDEX_NAME | INDEX_CREATED | INDEXED_TABLE_NAME | INDEXED_COLUMN_NAME | COLUMN_NULLABLE using views from my schema from data dictionary. It says that care should be taken because of the multi-column indexed columns do not double the results of the query. Can someone help me and maybe write example of code? Tnx

Comment: `It says that...` > What says that?

Comment: I mean, I need to take care of the multi-column indexed columns do not double but that is not important now....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select ic.table_name, ic.index_name,oc.last_ddl_time, ic.column_name, tc.DATA_TYPE, tc.DATA_LENGTH, tc.DATA_PRECISION,tc.DATA_SCALE, tc.NULLABLE
from user_ind_columns ic, user_tab_columns tc , user_objects oc
where 1=1
  and ic.table_name  = tc.TABLE_NAME
  and ic.column_name = tc.COLUMN_NAME
  and oc.object_name = ic.index_name
  and oc.object_type = 'INDEX'
order by ic.table_name, ic.index_name, ic.column_position;
```

Hi,
ic, tc, oc are aliases for index_columns, table_columns and user_objects. 
If You need YES/NO then use a decode:

```
select ic.table_name, ic.index_name,uo.last_ddl_time, ic.column_name, tc.DATA_TYPE, tc.DATA_LENGTH, tc.DATA_PRECISION,tc.DATA_SCALE, decode(tc.NULLABLE, 'Y', 'YES', 'N', 'NO')
from user_ind_columns ic, user_tab_columns tc , user_objects uo
where 1=1
  and ic.table_name  = tc.TABLE_NAME
  and ic.column_name = tc.COLUMN_NAME
  and uo.object_name = ic.index_name
  and uo.object_type = 'INDEX'
order by ic.table_name, ic.index_name, ic.column_position;
```

Regards rimetnac

Comment: What this means ic. , tc. , oc.????? ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.NULLABLE contains data Y / N, I need to print like YES / NO?